# Writing SpecFlow scenario that includes a prompt for a user decision

Tags: bdd, specflow

I'm new to SpecFlow and BDD and I've hit a roadblock in writing a scenario that requires a user to make a choice.  Essentially here is the scenario:

```
Scenario:  Deleting a record
Given I am on the edit record page
And I click the delete button
Then I should see a prompt asking for confirmation
```

I'm not sure how to proceed beyond this point.  There are two paths to test here, one for when the user says "OK" to the confirmation, and one for when the user says "Cancel".

I want to say "And If I click OK" followed by "Then the record should be deleted", etc.  But it seems like it should be broken up a better way.

How would you reword this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend writing your scenarios on a higher level. Avoid buttons, clicks and textboxes in your scenarios and try to talk about what the user want to accomplish - the behaviour of your system. The actual interaction with the page is then hidden in the step definitions.

So in your case that will be something like;

Given I am on the record page

When I delete a record

Then I should see a confirmation message

In the step definition for [When("I delete a record")] you then implement the clicking on the delete button and the Ok-button for "are you sure" or whatever is needed to delete the record.

I hope this was clear. Wrote it on my phone ;)

Comment: Thanks - That makes sense.  I suppose my next line would be something along the lines of "And a message should appear that my record was deleted."  In other words, giving me some place to put my test that the record was in fact deleted.  Does that sound correct or am I over-thinking this?

Comment: Ken, you can cover this with "Then I should see a confirmation message". You can rephrase it if it's important. +1 to Marcus for calling out the step levels. Doing it with buttons and clicks will be a maintenance nightmare!

Comment: @Lunivore - You're touching on one of the challenges I'm finding as I start to work in TDD, that is, where to draw the line.  I do think dealing with the UI (buttons and clicks and textboxes, oh my!) is a nuisance.  But on the web it is manageable if you make use of HTML element ids and classes.  Using an automation framework (I use Selenium 2 / WebDriver) I can easily act on an element, for example clicking it, adding text, checking for contents, etc.  I guess it all comes down to personal preference at some point.  I'm leaning towards the keep-it-high-level approach when writing specs.

Answer (score 2):

There might actually be three scenarios here.  The first one focusses as Marcus suggests:

```
Given I am on the record page
When I delete a record
Then I should see a confirmation message
```

But are there also scenarios for the behaviour of the confirmation dialog?

```
Given I am presented with a confirmation message
When I confirm the action
Then the action proceeds
```

And

```
Given I am presented with a confirmation message
When I cancel the action
Then the action does not proceed
```

Comment: You're right, there could be three scenarios. However, BDD isn't really about testing; it's about describing and exploring the behavior of the system so that everyone develops a common understanding, and whoever is changing it can do so safely. If you allow a different class to take on the responsibility of confirmation then you can delegate low-level behavior like this to your unit tests (mocking it out), and allow your scenarios to focus on higher-level, business-valuable capabilities.